# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My app keeps crashing and this error keeps popping up when my app is run on a API level 19 device after I updated Android Studio to 3.0. This app worked fine with previous Android Studio. Also the app works fine with API level 24 device now.

P.S. -  I know this question was asked some times before and its a duplicate. But none of the solutions worked for me.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bayasys.bayatrade.mobile-76.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.bayasys.bayatrade.mobile-76, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5236)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4828)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4711)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bayasys.bayatrade.mobile-76.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.bayasys.bayatrade.mobile-76, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4828) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4711) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the similar issue. I solved it by extending my Application class to MultidexApplication.

Comment: thanks @Anand. I actually solved it by re-installing my old Android Studio 2.3. Where did you extend it? from gradle?

Comment: No I have an application class from which I extended.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: you saved me Anand! Thanks!